# the output of 2nd for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

i have this code here and I am having a really hard time to figure out that isn't when i == 6 that would result in two results in the second loop when 6%2 = 0 and 6%3 = 0 and 6%4 =2. so how the compiler decides which if 6 is a prime number or not

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 2; i < 100 ; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) 
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}

private static boolean isPrime(int n) { 
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++){
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
        }
              return true;

}
```

Comment: Because when i is 6 as input argument, your code is going to return `false` directly and the for-loop stops, so that `6%3` and `6%4` will not never be reached. BTW, there are many errors in your code...

Comment: Like what please?!

Comment: You missed a left bracket in 2nd for-loop and you should move the `return true;` statement outside of it.

Comment: Yes i know this i was just trying to get the whole idea first, but thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are asking how the second loop knows 6 is prime or not.

In the second loop, if n is 6 then the loop will run once and then return false since 6%2==0. It will not check 6%3, 6%4 because the return statement was already called.

Basically, if the condition n%i== 0 is met, the return statement is called so no more values are checked. Remember that for prime numbers n%i == 0 can never be true anyways so there is no point in checking any other values.

Comment: I get your point but for a number like 9 it will also n%i  will not equal 0 so why doesn't the method recognize it as a prime number?!

Comment: Firstly, I would suggest looking at the loop formatted properly to make it easier to understand. Your for loop should have the if statement and the return false inside a bracket. For 9, the for loop will run until i becomes 9. So it will start with 9%2 then 9%3 and at 9%3 ==0 is true so it will return false. You need to remember that the loop will keep on running until the condition i < n is false.

Comment: Okay i get it now, so it only returns false if the argument for if statement is reached . But i have another question if you may, doesn't the return true; statement happens anyway wether there is even a loop or not?!

Comment: Correct, it will return false only when the if statement is true. But, the return true happens only when nothing else was returned. Basically, when the if statement is true, the loop stops and false is returned but if the loop ends without the if statement ever being true, then the return statment outside the loop is called. I think the reason you are confused is because you are maybe thining that the return statement only breaks the loop? The return statement returns a value to the method meaning that the method is done once a boolean value is returned. You can only return one boolean value

Answer (score 0):

This code prints every odd number as "prime" because the `isPrime` method will return **false** `if (n%2 == 0)` (first iteration), and **true** otherwise.

You could change your method to something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 2; i <100 ; i++) {
        if (isPrime (i)) 
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}

private static  boolean isPrime(int n) {    
    for (int i =2; i< n; i++)
        if (n%i == 0)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```